# Asynchronous CLI output

Tags: python, asynchronous, cmd, rabbitmq

So I'm writing this python RabbitMQ-based tool, using `cmd` for the CLI interface, that queries remote databases with the help of sending messages to clients on respective servers and getting messages with datasets back (some of the queries can take a long time and it needs to be asynchronous).

Example of a syntax would be something in lines of:

```
CLI> get host=myhost.com fact=cpunumber
```

This command will create a message to X clients to get the data.

Now, what I am struggling with is an approach to show the results of the queries in such a way that output will not be messy. Displaying results as soon as response dataset message arrives seems to be a bad UEX approach.

Anyone has implemented something like that and cares to share approaches?

I understand that this is not a very specific question, but maybe there will be some pointers to the text-mode formatting libraries that can be used in such situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no "good answer" to this question, I'll just share my thoughts on the subject.

I'm not sure why you feel that printing the data as soon as it arrives is bad design - immediacy is reassuring because it lets you know that something is working.

On the other hand, if the output looks messy, you might want to introduce some order. It is known that data sorted using some obvious criteria is more legible. Even more so - even bogus data, when sorted, looks more correct. ;)

Using your example, I'd try to sort it by host name or value for the given fact (whatever makes more sense in your case). If you know WHAT the data points are going to be (e.g. you query a list of known hosts), then you can sort output records as they arrive and print the parts that are known to be complete/coherent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, let me explain why I think that printing immediately is not a very good choice. Imagine that I query list of hardware facts about a number of servers. Each query would return, say 16 lines. And it comes from 4 different queues. As the user reads first result, at a random time another result pops up and shifts what he was looking at. Wouldn't you find that irritating? :)